# lxml, missing doctype when serialized

Tags: python, lxml, doctype

```
In [1]: from lxml import etree
```

I've got an HTML document:

```
In [2]: root = etree.fromstring(u'''<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN">\n<HTML></HTML>''', etree.HTMLParser())
```

Its doctype is parsed correctly:

```
In [3]: root.getroottree().docinfo.doctype
Out[3]: u'<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN">'
```

But when serializing it, I am losing it:

```
In [4]: etree.tostring(root.getroottree(), method='html')
Out[4]: '<html></html>'
```

What should I do to get that doctype serialized?

Debian GNU/Linux, Sid. Python 2.6.6. lxml 2.2.8-2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bug, as mentioned in a comment to another answer: [missing doctype when serialized](https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/659367). Fix in February 2015 to be released in version 3.5 of `lxml`.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I've been able to get it to work so far is by using the default XML parser and adding a non-empty system URL to the document:

```
>>> html = etree.parse(StringIO('''<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN" " ">\n<HTML></HTML>'''))
>>> etree.tostring(html, method="xml")
'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN" " ">\n<HTML/>'
>>> etree.tostring(html, method="html")
'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN" " ">\n<HTML></HTML>'
```

The same thing using the `HTMLParser` results in the same docinfo, but not the desired output:

```
>>> html = etree.parse(StringIO('''<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN" " ">\n<HTML></HTML>'''), etree.HTMLParser())
>>> etree.tostring(html, method="html")
'<html></html>'
```

Comment: Thanks, but my input is usually invalid XML -- therefore HTML parser. I filed a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxml/+bug/659367

Comment: No problem, I figured that might be the case.